# Spring @Autowired on a class with the same name as the current class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Say I have the below class in a Spring boot application:

```
@Configuration
public class Environment {
    @Autowired
    org.springframework.core.env.Environment environment;
}
```

When running this I get:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field environment in com.example.Environment required a bean of type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57780', transport: 'socket'
```

The workaround to fix this is just to rename my class from `public class Environment` to `public class Environments`

But I don't want to do that. How do keep my class name and also get Spring to realize what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `@Configuration("environments")` instead of renaming your class.

Answer (score 5):

You should give your configuration a name:

```
@Configuration(value = "myEnviroment")
public class Environment {}
```

From the `@Configuration` docs, regarding `value`:

> Explicitly specify the name of the Spring bean definition associated
>        with this Configuration class. **If left unspecified (the common case),
>        a bean name will be automatically generated**.
>        The custom name applies only if the Configuration class is picked up via
>        component scanning or supplied directly to a AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.

**Edit :**

And use the same name while autowiring this bean in your application with `@Qualifier` annotation like below :

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("myEnvironment")
private Environment environment;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but this answer still seems like a workaround since my bean isn't called `Environment`. I want it to stay the same and be called that everywhere and not have to change this value since I won't be using Spring's `Environment` anywhere else.

Comment: You can still use it anywhere you like (also if it is a bean why is it a `@Configuration` instead of `@Component` ?). Injection is done by type (by default) when using `@Autowired` and not by name (that is only a fallback).

Answer (score 0):

you can specify a bean name for you class , and Autowire to the new bean , at the end you are autowiring to beans to classes

```
      @Autowire("newname")
```